# fix eslint "no-unused-var" for defineEmits

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, eslint

I have a vue 3 app based on vue-cli with following structures:

tsconfig.js

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": [
      "webpack-env"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ],
      "~/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

.eslintrc.js

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,

  env: {
    node: true,
    'vue/setup-compiler-macros': true,
  },

  ignorePatterns: ['src/plugins/aliftech-ui', '.helm', 'werf-giterminism.yaml', 'werf.yaml', '.gitlab-ci.yml'],

  parserOptions: {
    parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  },

  rules: {
    'no-console': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'warn' : 'off',
    'no-debugger': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'warn' : 'off',
  },

  'extends': ['plugin:vue/vue3-essential', 'eslint:recommended', '@vue/prettier', '@vue/typescript'],
};
```

When defining props in a vue component:

```
  type Emits = {
    (e: 'set-main'): void;
  };
```

I get [following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TVjr.png) error

What I need is to tell eslint to ignore unused vars in defineEmits() but NOT for simple variables.

I tried to modiful .eslintrc.js file, but I could not find way how to tell eslint to ingore particularly unused vars in defineEmits()

Answer (score 2):

The eslint-plugin-vue [user guide](https://eslint.vuejs.org/user-guide/#does-not-work-well-with-script-setup) addresses both 'no-unused-vars' and 'no-undef' warnings with the same advice

> **Compiler macros such as defineProps and defineEmits generate no-undef warnings**
>
> You need to use [vue-eslint-parser](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-eslint-parser) v9.0.0 or later.

Comment: This solves only defineEmits and defineProps compiler macro problems, but I need to solve problem with defining type for Emits